# Unable to reset stream after calculating AWS4 signature

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, inputstream, java-io

There is piece of code.

```
 List<PartETag> uploadPartsOfAsset(AssetUploadRequestVO requestVO) {
    final SingleClient singleClient = clientProvider.getClient(requestVO.getAssetKind());
    final List<PartETag> parts = new ArrayList<>();
    final String key = String.join(DELIMITER, requestVO.getClientName(), requestVO.getAssetGroup(), requestVO.getAssetName());

    final long contentSize = requestVO.getContentSize();
    long position = 0;
    long partSize = minPartSize;

    final UploadPartRequest request = new UploadPartRequest();

    try (InputStream source = requestVO.getSource()) {
        for (int partNumber = requestVO.getPartNumber(); position < requestVO.getContentSize(); partNumber++) {
            partSize = Math.min(partSize, (requestVO.getContentSize() - position));

            final long nextFilePosition = position + partSize;
            if((requestVO.getContentSize() - nextFilePosition) < minPartSize){
                partSize = contentSize - position;
                position = contentSize;
            }

            request.withBucketName(singleClient.getBucketName())
                    .withKey(key)
                    .withUploadId(requestVO.getUploadId()).withPartNumber(partNumber)
                    .withInputStream(source)
                    .withPartSize(partSize);

            PartETag partETag = null;
            try {
                partETag = singleClient.getAmazonS3Client().uploadPart(request).getPartETag();
            } catch (AmazonS3Exception e){
                throw new AssetNotFoundException(e.getMessage());
            }
            parts.add(partETag);

            position += partSize;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new AssetUploadException("The asset cannot be upload.", e);
    }

    return parts;
}
```

AssetUploadRequestVO.getSource() is instance of  S3ObjectInputStream. The problem is that this throw exception:

```
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to reset stream after calculating AWS4 signature
at com.amazonaws.auth.AWS4Signer.calculateContentHash(AWS4Signer.java:542) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.125.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.AWSS3V4Signer.calculateContentHash(AWSS3V4Signer.java:118) ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.125.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.auth.AWS4Signer.sign(AWS4Signer.java:213) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.125.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1164) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.125.jar:na]
```

...

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Resetting to invalid mark
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.reset(BufferedInputStream.java:448) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkBufferedInputStream.reset(SdkBufferedInputStream.java:106) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.125.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.reset(SdkFilterInputStream.java:102) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.125.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.event.ProgressInputStream.reset(ProgressInputStream.java:168) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.125.jar:na]
```

I've already found how to solve this bug, but problem is that I really don't understand why it happened.

So the solution is changing S3ObjectInputStream to other input stream. In my case I've changed it to:

```
new ByteArrayInputStream(IOUtils.toByteArray(requestVO.getSource()))
```

So could someone help me please and explain what problem is in, and is my solution good? 
Also I would like to add that this code works fine if we use S3 and fails only with ECS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that Stream returned from EC2 does not support mark. You have to save it to FileInputStream or ByteArrayInputStream. Or in my case merge everything inside amazon without fetching it to my server